# Change context style menu windows 10

Tags: windows, themes, customization, msstyles

I managed to interpret a mmstyles file through a tool called "msstylesEditor" but I can't find where I can modify the values for the background and font color of the context menu.

Also if anyone could link me to some tutorials on how to make theme like those found on DeviantArt i'd be glad ! I couldn't find anything !

[Here is how msstylesEditor looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaGFk.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background can be changed under `Menu -> POPUPBACKGROUND`. This is an image (1x1px). You have to export it, change its color, then replace the old image.

You also might want to look at the `POPUPBORDER` and `POPUPITEM` parts, in order to fully change the menus appearance. I havent verified where the font color is located, but i guess its the `TEXTCOLOR` properties
of the just stated parts.

The aim of the tool you linked, is mainly to **modify** existing themes. The styles on DeviantArt are probably made using a (commercial) tool called "Windows Style Builder".

Comment: Damn thanks a lot ! I wonder why those there isn't more tutorial online...

Comment: @MatthieuPOIROT Because this UI system is largely depreciated after Windows 7 and Microsoft doesn't like users mucking around with UI. It's sad! After spending the last couple of months with Gnome and GTK coming back to Windows has been hard :(